# Web Api Json model validation stops at first error

Tags: json, validation, model, webapi

I have a .NET 6 WebApi project, I need to validate the input of a POST call and in case of invalid data I have to return a BadRequest response with a list of every invalid field.

To do this I'm returning BadRequest passing the modelstate that should contain all the invalid fields.

When I try to call this API sending invalid input data I get an error with only the first invalid property of the object, but I want to receive every invalid request field.

I have created a little program to replicate this behaviour

This is the controller

```
[ApiController]
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("home")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost("hello")]
    public IActionResult Hello([FromBody]MyModel m)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid) return BadRequest(ModelState);
        else return Ok();
    }
}
```

This is MyModel class

```
public class MyModel
{
    public DateTime DateFrom { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTo { get; set; }
}
```

the Programs.cs is the default one created by VisualStudio

When I send this input (that is invalid in both DateFrom and DateTo field)

```
{
  "dateFrom": "iii",
  "dateTo": "iii"
}
```

I get

```
{
  "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
  "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
  "status": 400,
  "traceId": "00-b0479ed73904a596cdad2af4560480ee-c8b643fd27134cb2-00",
  "errors": {
    "m": [
      "The m field is required."
    ],
    "$.dateFrom": [
      "The JSON value could not be converted to System.DateTime. Path: $.dateFrom | LineNumber: 1 | BytePositionInLine: 19."
    ]
  }
}
```

with only dateFrom field, but I'm expecting both of them.

Do you know if there is a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I did a lot of tries and the only solution I've found is changing the json library used to validate input: from System.Text.Json to Newtonsoft.Json.